# What is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{an^2 + bn + c}$ ?  or: is $0.0100100010000100001...$ transcendental?

Tags: sequences-and-series, transcendental-numbers

The idea is a more convenient form for $N = 0.01001000100001000001...$ in base $r$, hopefully to show whether it is transcendental.

Sorry for brevity.

Comment: We can factor out an $r^c$ term from the sum. For special values of $a$ and $b$, the sum is expressible in terms of Jacobi theta functions, but I know of no closed form for the general form you have.

Comment: let's say $r=2^{-1/2}$, $a=1$, $b=5$, $c=4$, which I think makes the series equal to $N$ in binary. Also, thanks for fixing my TeX.

Comment: The $b=5$ portion would be troublesome in figuring a closed form for what you say you have...

Comment: @J.M. I tried to complete the squares hoping to kill the linear term, but it didn't work because $5$ "happened" to be an odd number. Did you anticipate this in your comment? Also, if I gave you just $an^2+c$, then do closed-form solutions exist?

Comment: Yeah, something like that @Srivatsan. ;) For your much simpler case, you have a representation in terms of the third Jacobi theta function: $\frac{r^c}{2}(1+\vartheta_3(0,r^a))$

Comment: "their applicability would depend on the quadratic not containing the linear term." - not necessarily, @Srivatsan. You'll notice for instance that the series for the second Jacobi theta function involves triangular number exponents...

Comment: @J.M. Grrr, I don't know why I am getting all muddled up with these formulas. Thanks for pointing it to me. I think I will look at them carefully after I get some sleep. :-) (Btw I guess I'll just delete my previous redundant comments tomorrow.)

Comment: No need @Sri; at least you've provided the opportunity for me to mention the "cream puff" cases. ;)

Comment: In the title, it's natural to take $r=1/10$, but in the body it's evident that $r$ is meant to be 10. We can square these by having $r=10$ and $a\lt0$, but maybe it's more natural to write $\sum r^{-(an^2+bn+c)}$ with a quadratic that's non-negative for non-negative $n$.

Answer (score 7):

Of course $N$ is transcendental.  [I said it is, I didn't say I can prove it.]  It is conjectured that all irrational algebraic numbers are normal in all bases.  If this were not transcendental, it would be a spectacular counterexample to that conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

This may come under the heading of "Siegel E-functions" or "Siegel G-functions", for which transcendence results are known.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a technique for this sort of sum (though this doesn't address the transcendentality question) I found a while ago which involves incomplete theta functions:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{an^{2}+2akn+ak^{2}+p} = q^{p}\left[\frac{\theta_{3}(0,q^{a})+1}{2} - \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} q^{am^{2}}\right]
\end{equation}

for example:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{7n^{2}+70n+173}} = e^{2}\left[\frac{\theta_{3}(0,1/e^{7})+1}{2} - \sum_{m=0}^{4} (1/e^{7})^{m^2}\right]
\end{equation}

I'm not sure it works for arbitrary $a$, $b$, and $c$, though.